# How to programmatically add a language in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm in drupal 7 and I want to programmatically add a language except the default language when I'm writing a new profile. And set it to default.

I don't want to use translation:
http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads

Can anyone help?!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the Locale [locale_add_language](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!locale.inc/function/locale_add_language/7) function. It is possible to create new languages. It also allows to set newly created language as default. In addition you can set default language by setting "language_default" variable to language **object**.

```
variable_set('language_default', $default);
```